# django-rest-auth: Custom Register Serializer not saving custom fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

> **NOT A DUPLICATE**

I am building a simple `Todo` app with `Django` & `ReactJs`, and i have ran into a problem with `django-rest-auth`.

the problem is that my custom `UserRegisterSerializer` only saves a fragment of the `request.data`and ignore the rest. and i have no idea why.

Here's my code:

User Model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4,
                      primary_key=True, unique=True, editable=False, db_index=True)

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=247, blank=False, 
                unique=True, error_messages={
                    'unique': _('A user with this email already exists.'),
                    'invalid': _('Invalid e-mail address detected.'),
                    'blank': _('this field may not be blank.')
                })

    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, 
                unique=True, error_messages={
                     'unique': _('A user with this phone number already exists.'),
                })

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=GENDERS, default=NOOP)
    birthday = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    @property
    def user_id(self):
        return self.id
```

RegisterSerializer(Custom):

```
class UserRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=True, max_length=100)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(
        write_only=True, required=True, max_length=100)

    birthday = serializers.DateField(required=True, write_only=True)
    phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, write_only=True, 
             validators=[
                    UniqueValidator(
                       User.objects.all(),
                       message=_('A user with this phone number already exists.')
                    )
             ])

    gender = serializers.ChoiceField(
        write_only=True,
        choices=[
            ('NO-OP', 'Rather not tell'),
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
        ],
        default='NO-OP'
    )

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        cleaned_data = super().get_cleaned_data()
        cleaned_data['first_name'] = self.validated_data.get('first_name', '')
        cleaned_data['last_name'] = self.validated_data.get('last_name', '')
        cleaned_data['phone'] = self.validated_data.get('phone', '')
        cleaned_data['birthday'] = self.validated_data.get('birthday', '')
        cleaned_data['gender'] = self.validated_data.get('gender', '')
        print(cleaned_data)
        return cleaned_data
```

output of `print(cleaned_data)`:

```
{'username': 'john_doe', 'password1': 'djangopass', 'email': 'john_doe@email.com', 'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe', 'phone': '+555 555 5555', 'birthday': datetime.date(2020, 6, 3), 'gender': 'M'}
```

Saved user Model:

[saved_model_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcXId.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue by using a custom `UserAdapter`.

here's the code of `adapter.py`:

```
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter
from allauth.account.utils import user_field

class UserAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=True):
         data = form.cleaned_data
         birthday = data.get('birthday')
         phone = data.get('phone')
         gender = data.get('gender')
         if birthday:
             setattr(user, 'birthday', birthday)
         if phone:
             user_field(user, 'phone', phone)
         if gender:
             user_field(user, 'gender', gender)
         return super().save_user(request, user, form, commit=commit)
```

then in your `settings.py`:

```
...
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'accounts.adapter.UserAdapter'
...
```

Answer (score 4):

I did it with a save method in my CustomRegisterSerializer calling the default save method and updating attributes, for example:

I needed to fill first and last name and profile:

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    profile = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()
        return {
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('first_name', ''),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'id': self.validated_data.get('id', ''),
            'profile': self.validated_data.get('profile','')
        }
    def save(self, request):
        user = super().save(request)
        user.profile = self.data.get('profile')
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Remember add the REGISTER_SERIALIZER in settings.py
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    'REGISTER_SERIALIZER': 'webapi.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer'
}